# can not automatically login without typing www in url

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, url-rewriting

i have a website and the problem is that if i'm logged in and open another tab of same browser on which i'm logged in than if i type my site name without using www than it won't redirect me to the dashboard but when i use sitename with wwww and i'm logged in than it redirect me to corresponding dashboard automatically.

i need to resolve this issue that whether i type website address with or without www, and i'm logged in, so it should takes me directly to the dashboard, rather than staying at home page and asking for login.

if this question is already posted kindly reffer me to that as i couldn't find it.

```
    # Use PHP5CGI as default
   AddDefaultCharset utf-8
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
  </IfModule>
```

Thank you in advance

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Codeigniter uses cookie based session so whenever you login without www its setting cookie for yourdomain.com and when you are changing the url with www i.e www.example.com so there is no cookie for this domain your app didn't get session cookie and it asks for login.

Answer (score 0):

Please show us the .htaccess file. If it is empty you can write a rule to redirect yourdomain.com to www.yourdomain.com.
Maybe this can solve your issue.

Comment: i have update my question and added .htaccess file which i'm using to remove index.php from the url.